# How do I run a hadoop jar from another program?

Tags: java, hadoop, jobs

I have the following function that I need to implement:

```
public void CreateMRJob(String jobInputLocation, String jobJarLocation);
```

This might seem rather simple and a duplicate question, but I would like to perform the initialization of the job in a separate file (WPMampReduce.java as attached below) as the user would be allowed to edit some parts of it. Here's what I mean when I say initialize the job in a separate file:

```
// WPMapReduce.java
public class WPMapReduce {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "WPMapReduce");

    job.setSpeculativeExecution(false);
    job.setReduceSpeculativeExecution(false);
    job.setJarByClass(WPMapReduce.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setSpeculativeExecution(false);
    job.setReduceSpeculativeExecution(false);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}
```

I am not sure how would I set the jar file as the job to be run and then  run the job from the function CreateMRJob which is in a different file.

P.S. I am new to hadoop and I might be assuming a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

One way to perform this would be by creating a sub-process using Runtime.exec() in java to get access to the command-line (terminal in linux or mac or cmd in Windows) and setting the parameters and running the job. The output file can store the data while you can create a pipe to stream data from the job while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to create a separate Class with main, you can have a MRSetup Class wherein you can read a config(property) file with the required parameters and prepare the Object.
The same object you can be used in the MR-Driver-Job class.